# PHP S3 deleteBucketAsync wierd working

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a little problem with AWS S3 service. I'm trying to delete whole bucket and i would like to use `deleteBucketAsync()`.

My code:

```
    $result = $this->s3->listObjects(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
        'Prefix' => ''
    ));
    foreach($result['Contents'] as $file){
      $this->s3->deleteObjectAsync(array(
        'Bucket' =>  $bucket_name,
        'Key'    => $file['Key']
      ));
    }

        $result = $this->s3->deleteBucketAsync(
            [
                'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            ]
        );
```

Sometimes this code works and delete whole bucket in seconds. But sometimes it doesn't.
Can someone please explain me how exacly S3 async functions work?

Comment: What is the `$result` when the delete fails?

Comment: $result was empty. Problem has been solved by promises.